# Awk get unique elements from array

Tags: awk

file.txt:

```
INTS11:P446P&INTS11:P449P&INTS11:P518P&INTS11:P547P&INTS11:P553P
PLCH2:A1007int&PLCH1:D987int&PLCH2:P977L
```

I am attempting to create a hyperlink by transforming the content of a file. The hyperlink will have the following style:

```
somelink&gene=<gene>[&gene=<gene>]&mutation=<gene:key>[&mutation=<gene:key>]
```

where `INTS11:P446P` corresponds to `gene:key` for example

The problem is that I am looping on the each row to create an array that contains the `genes` as values and thus multiple duplicated entries can be found for the same `gene`.

My attempt is the following

1. Split on `&` and store in `a`
2. For each element in `a`, split on `:` and add `a[i]` to array `b`

The problem is that I don't know how to get unique values from my array. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532283/how-to-only-add-unique-elements-to-an-array-in-awk-from-sevral-input-text-files) but it talks about files and not arrays like in my case.

The code:

```
awk '@include "join"
    {
    split($0,a,"&")
    for ( i = 1; i <= length(a); i++ ) {
        split(a[i], b, ":");
        genes[i] = "&gene="b[1];
        keys[i] = "&mutation="b[1]":"b[2]
    }
    print "somelink"join(genes, 1, length(genes),SUBSEP)join(keys, 1, length(keys),SUBSEP)
    delete genes
    delete keys
}' file.txt
```

will output:

```
somelink&gene=INTS11&gene=INTS11&gene=INTS11&gene=INTS11&gene=INTS11&mutation=INTS11:P446P&mutation=INTS11:P449P&mutation=INTS11:P518P&mutation=INTS11:P547P&mutation=INTS11:P553P
somelink&gene=PLCH2&gene=PLCH1&gene=PLCH2&mutation=PLCH2:A1007int&mutation=PLCH1:D987int &mutation=PLCH2:P977L
```

I wish to obtain something similar like (notice how many `&gene=` is there):

```
somelink&gene=INTS11&mutation=INTS11:P446P&INTS11:P449P&INTS11:P518P&INTS11:P547P&INTS11:P553P
somelink&gene=PLCH2&gene=PLCH1&mutation=PLCH2:A1007int&mutation=PLCH1:D987int&mutation=PLCH2:P977L
```

EDIT:

my problem was partly solved thanks to Pierre Francois's answer which was the `SUBSEP`. My other issue is that I want to get only unique elements from my arrays `genes` and `keys`.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing this would not be terribly hard to solve if I could understand what you actually want, but your exposition fails to explain what the fields in the input are or how they should map to the output fields. Could you give another go at outlining *exactly* what your goal is?

Comment: What is the problem? What do you mean with "printing join adds space to result" in the title of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you want to remove the spaces between the fields concatenated with the *join* function of **awk**, the 4th argument you have to provide to the *join* function is the magic number `SUBSEP` and not an empty string `""` as you did. Try:

```
awk '@include "join"
    {
    split($0,a,"&")
    for ( i = 1; i <= length(a); i++ ) {
        split(a[i], b, ":");
        genes[i] = "&gene="b[1];
        keys[i] = "&mutation="b[1]":"b[2]
    }
    print "somelink"join(genes, 1, length(genes),SUBSEP)join(keys, 1, length(keys),SUBSEP)
    delete genes
    delete keys
}' file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for the late reply. This partly answers my problem. I will Edit my OP for more info