# Awk create a new array of unique values from another array

Tags: awk

I have my array:

```
array = [1:"PLCH2", 2:"PLCH1", 3:"PLCH2"]
```

I want to loop on `array` to create a new array `unique` of unique values and obtain:

```
unique = [1:"PLCH2", 2:"PLCH1"]
```

how can I achieve that ?

EDIT: as per @Ed Morton request, I show below how my array is populated. In fact, this post is the key solution to my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60080270/awk-get-unique-elements-from-array).

in my `file.txt`, I have:

```
PLCH2:A1007int&PLCH1:D987int&PLCH2:P977L
INTS11:P446P&INTS11:P449P&INTS11:P518P&INTS11:P547P&INTS11:P553P
```

I use split to obtain `array`:

```
awk '{
    split($0,a,"&")
    for ( i in a ) {
        split(a[i], b, ":");
        array[i] = b[1];
    }
}' file.txt
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include a small, complete script that shows how your current array is populated because what you have posted so far could be interpreted in several different ways.

Comment: `for ( i in a )` will re-arrange your values into a random (hash) order. That's often undesirable which is why I use `for ( i=1; i in a; i++ )` instead to ensure I visit the array indices in the same order they appeared in the string that was split into the array. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array.

Comment: @EdMorton wow I didn't know that, thanks for explaining the different in the loop

Comment: @EdMorton Huh, I usually use `for (i = 1; i <= length(a); i++)` to do the same (assuming the array `a` has numeric indices, which is true for arrays generated by the `split()` function). I wasn't sure if the `i in a` condition is in proper order - do you know if it works with all awks? (Well, I mostly care about BWK AWK, mawk, and gawk.)

Comment: @jena calling `length(a)` on each iteration of the loop is time consuming vs a hash lookup and is non-portable (per POSIX, `length()` operates on strings, not arrays). `i in a` in this context has nothing (directly) to do with order, it's just a hash lookup testing if `i` is an index of `a` which will fail when `i` has the value 1 more than the max index. Yes, it works in all awks, unlike `length(a)` which will only work in awks that support calling length on an array.

Comment: Aha, interesting. I guess I was lucky to not get burned by this yet ️. I now realize it will give the elements in order because of the increment `i++`, stupid me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split("PLCH2 PLCH1 PLCH2",array)

    printf "array ="
    for (i=1; i in array; i++) {
        printf " %s:\"%s\"", i, array[i]
    }
    print ""

    for (i=1; i in array; i++) {
        if ( !seen[array[i]]++ ) {
            unique[++j] = array[i]
        }
    }

    printf "unique ="
    for (i=1; i in unique; i++) {
        printf " %s:\"%s\"", i, unique[i]
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk
array = 1:"PLCH2" 2:"PLCH1" 3:"PLCH2"
unique = 1:"PLCH2" 2:"PLCH1"
```

---

EDIT: given your updated question, here's how I'd really approach that:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[:&]" }
{
    numVals=0
    for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {
        vals[++numVals] = $i
    }

    print "vals =" arr2str(vals)

    delete seen
    numUniq=0
    for (i=1; i<=numVals; i++) {
        if ( !seen[vals[i]]++ ) {
            uniq[++numUniq] = vals[i]
        }
    }

    print "uniq =" arr2str(uniq)
}

function arr2str(arr,    str, i) {
    for (i=1; i in arr; i++) {
        str = str sprintf(" %s:\"%s\"", i, arr[i])
    }
    return str
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
vals = 1:"PLCH2" 2:"PLCH1" 3:"PLCH2"
uniq = 1:"PLCH2" 2:"PLCH1"
vals = 1:"INTS11" 2:"INTS11" 3:"INTS11" 4:"INTS11" 5:"INTS11"
uniq = 1:"INTS11" 2:"PLCH1"
```

Comment: Thanks for proposing an answer, I will try it out and come back to this. Btw, is `seen` a function ?

Comment: No, `seen[]` is just a name of an array that I'm using to store the values from `array[]` as indices so I can identify which of those values has been seen before by it's associated count be zero or non-zero (which I'm using as false or true in the `if`). `seen[]` COULD be named anything but that's the idiomatic name given to an array used for that purpose.

Comment: @Zen others had already rejected [your proposed edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25323042) before I saw it in the queue but it had several issues anyway so I just posted how to really do this using the sample input you provided read from a file.

Comment: Sorry for the necrobump, but still, I can't get this `i!seen[array[i]]++` condition... You check if `seen` has  an index (key), which equals `array[i]`..? And if it doesn't, you assign that index to `unique` (incrementing `j` before the assignment, that I *do* get). **But what does this increment in the condition do?**

Comment: @AS `seen[x]++` tests if the index `x` has been seen before. The first time `seen[x]++` is tested the result is false since the value of `seen[x]` is zero, but the second (and subsequent times) it's true because the `++` that was executed after the condition was evaluated the first time set `seen[x]` to 1. Any time you see an array named `seen[]`  THAT is what it's being used for (assuming the person who wrote the code understands the idiom).

Comment: @EdMorton, Really thank you for your time and support. One more question: can this part be re-written in a somehow more elaborate way? Like, with more `if`s may be and without the increment? Possibly seeing a more detailed, more step-by-step code could finalise my take on it... Sorry for being not really a programmer -- I've just never seen this approach before... :)

Comment: @AS you're welcome. I expect so - post a new question specifically about whatever it is you want to know about and leave me a comment and I'll take a look. Just make sure to make it about performing a specific task and not "can someone explain this code" or similar and include a [mcve] so it doesn't get downvoted and closed as off topic.

Comment: It's extremely simple though so I suspect you're overthinking it. Execute `printf 'a\nb\na\n' | awk '!seen[$0]++{print NR, $0}'` and `printf 'a\nb\na\n' | awk 'seen[$0]++{print NR, $0}'`. Now do you understand what `seen[x]++` does? In particular `awk '!seen[$0]++'` behaves like the unix command `uniq` but the values don't need to be contiguous.

Comment: If it's still not clear, please do post a question.

Comment: @EdMorton, I posted a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71396485/creating-a-unique-array-in-awk-can-this-snippet-be-elaborated :) (And I agree, I'm probably overthinking it, but just hit a block and can't find a way out :)