# Creating a unique array in awk: can this snippet be elaborated?

Tags: arrays, awk

[Thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60157991/1068046) to @EdMorton, I can unique an array in awk this way:

```
BEGIN {
    # create an array 
    # here, I create an array from a string, but other approaches are possible, too
    split("a b c d e a b", array)

    # unique it
    for (i=1; i in array; i++) {
        if ( !seen[array[i]]++ ) {
            unique[++j] = array[i]
        }
    }

    # print out the result
    for (i=1; i in unique; i++) {
        print unique[i]
    }
    # results in:
    # a
    # b
    # c
    # d
    # e
}
```

What I don't understand, though, is this `( !seen[array[i]]++ )` condition with an increment:

1. I do understand that we collect unique indices in the `seen` array;
2. So, we check if our temp array `seen` already has an index `array[i]` (and add it to unique, if it hasn't);
3. But the increment after the index is the thing I still can't get :) (despite [the detailed explanation provided by Ed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60155850/awk-create-a-new-array-of-unique-values-from-another-array/60157991?noredirect=1#comment126195732_60157991)).

So, my question is the following: can we somehow re-write this conditional in a more elaborate way? May be this would really help to finalise  my take on it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is clearer but idk - best I can say is it's more elaborate as requested!

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    # create an array
    # here, I create an array from a string, but other approaches are possible, too
    split("a b c d e a b", array)

    # unique it
    for (i=1; i in array; i++) {
        val = array[i]
        count[val] = count[val] + 1

        if ( count[val] == 1 ) {
            is_first_time_val_seen = 1
        }
        else {
            is_first_time_val_seen = 0
        }

        if ( is_first_time_val_seen ) {
            unique[++j] = val
        }
    }

    # print out the result
    for (i=1; i in unique; i++) {
        print unique[i]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk
a
b
c
d
e
```

Comment: Damn! Thanks to beer, I got it: when we add a key to this dict (this temp `seen` array), it can't stay empty, we have to assign something to it in order to distinguish it from keys, which are NOT present in the array. Thus, an increment -- and this whole construct  `seen[array[i]]++` is just  literally the same as `some_var++`, nothing more, it immediately becomes 1 after being declared (like, `{"array[i]": 1}`) and only increments  afterwards, which results in FALSE in the reversed `!` conditional. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to put `array`'s *values* into a new *associative* array as *keys*. That will enforce uniqueness:

```
BEGIN {
  # it's helpful to use the return value from `split`
  n = split("a b c d e a b", array)

  # use the element value as a key.
  # It doesn't really matter what the right-hand side of the assignment is.
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) uniq[array[i]] = i

  # now, it's easy to iterate over the unique keys
  for (elem in uniq) print elem
}
```

outputs in no guaranteed order:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

if you're using GNU awk, use [`PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) to control sorting of the array traversal

Comment: Indeed, your approach is way more familiar to me personally, and yes, it took me quite a time to grok that in AWK empty keys are non exactly distinguishable from non-present keys.